# Как в qt в pro файле указать подключение библиотеки только для Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Я подключаю библиотеку в *Linux*:

```
unix:!macx:LIBS += -lXtst -lX11
```

т.е. она подключается только в *Linux*. А как мне сделать такое же только для *Windows*?

На библиотеку, которую надо подключить, *Linux* ругается.

```
LIBS += -lws2_32
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
win32: {
    LIBS += -lws2_32
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало :)

Comment: @MadokaMagika отметьте как правильный ответ